# Django: output of parameters

Tags: python, objective-c, django, json, debugging

Is there a way to print the parameters in order to debug views in Django?
I've tried do the following:

```
def print_request(request):
    f = open('some_file.txt', 'w+')
    f.write("testing")
    for key in request.POST:
        value = request.POST[key]
        f.write(value)
    f.close()
    return HttpResponse("Done")
```

the function returns "Done" value, the file is created with testing inside, but nothing from the request this is what I'm passing in objective-c

```
-(void)callServer
{
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string", @"string", @"string", nil];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"description", @"icon", @"showOnMap", nil];
    NSDictionary *questionDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:questionDict forKey:@"question"];

    id json = [NSJSONSerialization
               dataWithJSONObject:questionDict
               options:0
               error:nil];

    NSLog(@"jsonRequest is %@", json);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:test_POST_URL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];


    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[json UTF8String] length:[json length]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    NSError* error;
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        NSDictionary* jsonAddressResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    }
}
```

can't figure out why isn't this working

Answer (score 0):

Python has a  somewhat complete logging module as part of the stdlib and for recent versions of Django it's already partly configured to send logging messages to stderr. That's the standard official and RightWay to do logging in any python code. Now you can also just plain write to stderr directly but that's really not a good idea for production code.

Also note that if running the built in deb server you can also add a breakpoint in your code to inspect the request (and anything in the whole call stack) directly.

Comment: I'm running on a google compute engine instance and writing code with simple editor of nano, what ide i should install to be able to use breakpoints?